# Trying to add paypal "view cart" to existing site navigation

Tags: paypal, navigation, cart

I am trying to add the below PayPal code for a "View Cart" button to my existing site navigation. The site is here: [Test Site](http://www.petraballet.com/wordpress/)

Is there a way to wrap this in a ul nav? I'm a designer by trade, I know HTML, CSS, some PHP, but I don't know how to handle this. Thanks!

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----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-----END PKCS7-----">
<input type="image" src="http://i1277.photobucket.com/albums/y493/Petra_Ballet_Company/Product/ViewCart_Button_Over_zps5ef146f4.jpg" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a view cart button at www.paypal.com (you may have to view an add to cart/shopping cart button's code first, then click below to create a view cart and generate it)  and when viewing the view cart button code, switch from the 'Website' tab to 'Email' to get a link.

This works for any button that doesn't have an input like a selection box or a text field.  Also if you want to expose the underlying variables, you can uncheck "Save button at PayPal" under Step 2 and then remove code protection when viewing the code.

Comment: This option will kind of work for now. I wanted to be able to edit the paypal button code so I could have over state for the button, but I found a work around. I just used a one pixel black square for the image, and it doesn't show up. Thanks!